# download video of type mp4 without url ending in mp4

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am a newbie at web development, my question is, as I understand this code below, it will open the Chrome Video Player, which also has a download button which can download the video.

How can I get the real url for the video which end in an extension of mp4?

```
<video loop muted playsinline   autoplay="autoplay" preload width="640" height="360">
    <source src="https://r4---sn-nv47lney.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?lmt=1517456704789231&key=cms1&dur=386.240&ipbits=0&requiressl=yes&mime=video%2Fmp4&source=youtube&pl=20&itag=18&ei=hudyXP-4OIXlwQHBsaOwAw&gir=yes&expire=1551055847&ratebypass=yes&c=WEB&fvip=4&id=o-AHZWBPA4mUtFjI305r97oXdDZELtWbNS5dJeuwGAqirn&clen=23249888&ip=2600%3A3c00%3A%3Af03c%3A91ff%3Afe52%3Af0d3&sparams=clen,dur,ei,expire,gir,id,ip,ipbits,ipbypass,itag,lmt,mime,mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source&signature=41173E731E2CFF1D3BB61936B8A78716C9515442.358D2657A715DA85E175DB497BC6D211489DA79E&title=Very+Powerful+Motivational+Video+For+Medical+Students.+Goosebumps+Guaranteed!!!&redirect_counter=1&rm=sn-q4fels76&req_id=4c1bf6c1b1eb36e2&cms_redirect=yes&ipbypass=yes&mip=192.123.1.4&mm=31&mn=sn-nv47lney&ms=au&mt=1551034152&mv=m#t=0.9" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"the real url"_? Not sure what the problem is. Are you referring to the full video? Note that `#t=0.9` is a media fragment URI which begins the media at the time slice `0.9`. For the full playback of media you can remove the media fragment URI from the URL.

Comment: this link that is upove is a link for a youtube video,and i mean by the real link is the link for the actual video that ends in mp4 extension like "aomething.mp4"

Comment: i understand that,but what i meant withthe link upove i CANNOT download the video,it is only downloadable by using chrome video player download button

Comment: There are several approaches which could be used to "download" the file, one of which is using youtube-dl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-dl

Comment: http://we-appit.com/Vid/with.html